# Conditional expected outcome with two random variables

Tags: probability

Assume two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Assume the following random outcomes. If $X<Y$ and $Y<a$, the reward is $W_1$. If $X<Y$ and $Y>a$, the reward is $W_2$. If $X>Y$ and $Y<a$, the reward is $W_3$. If $X<Y$ and $Y>a$, the reward is $W_4$.

If we went to find the expected reward, what is the correct way of finding the probabilities? Do we use conditional probabilities?

Is this the correct expected reward?: $\Biggr(W_1*P(X<Y|Y<a)+W_3*P(X>Y|Y<a)\Biggr)P(Y<a)+\Biggr(W_2*P(X<Y|Y>a)+W_4*P(X>Y|Y>a)\Biggr)P(Y>a)$

There is a problem here; $P(Y<a)$ is cancelled out by the denaminator of the conditional probability $P(X<Y|Y<a)$.

Comment: "There is a problem here; P(Y<a) is cancelled out by the denaminator of the conditional probability P(X<Y|Y<a)." Why is this a problem to you?

Comment: If $P(Y<a)$ is cancelled out, what is left is the expectation $W_1*P(X<Y)+W_3*P(X>Y)$, which is not correct

Comment: No. What is $P(X<Y\mid Y<a)P(Y<a)$, say?

Comment: You have $W=W_1\mathbf1_{X<Y,Y<a}+W_2\mathbf1_{X<Y,Y>a}+W_3\mathbf1_{X>Y,Y<a}+W_4\mathbf1_{X<Y,Y>a}$. So, $E(W)=E(W_1\mathbf1_{X<Y,Y<a})+E(W_2\mathbf1_{X<Y,Y>a})+E(W_3\mathbf1_{X>Y,Y<a})+E(W_4\mathbf1_{X<Y,Y>a})$.

Comment: $P(X<Y|Y<a)=\frac{P(X<Y \cap Y<a)}{P(Y<a)}$

Comment: $P(X<Y|Y<a)P(Y<a)=P(X<Y\cap Y<a)$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** use the indicator function $1_a(x)$ for real $x$ that evaluates to 1 if $x>a$ and 0 elsewhere.

This will help to write $W(X,Y)$ as a sum of what you need, and then use linearity of expected values.